# How to convert this table in a better JSON format in Pandas's favor

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas

I have no idea, what's the better way to convert the HTML table into JSON that meets Pandas dataframe favor.

I will store the JSON in MongoDB then send the JSON data to Pandas when it needs.

[image]

The following is my draft idea, But it seems not good.

```
{
    table_name: "Change in real GDP"
    measure: "Actual",
    year: [2009, 2010, ..]
    value: [0.2, 2.7,...]
}

{
    table_name: "Change in real GDP"
    measure: "Upper End of Range",
    year: [2009, 2010, ..]
    value: [-, -,...]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Well its good practice to keep common things separate as I can see in your JSON table name is repeating in each json. We can keep it out side.
2. Its better to group year and value in one json else you have to take care of index of both values while reading JSON. 
   So your json looks someting like this

   ```
   var data = 
   {
        table_name: "Change in real GDP",
        eachRow : [
             {
                measure: "Actual",
                columndetails : [
                  {
                       year : "2009",
                       value : "-"
                   }    
                ]
            }
       ]
   };
   ```

to read data

```
// for each row in table
for(var i=0; i< data.eachRow.length; i++){
    var eachRowData = data.eachRow[i];
    // for each column in row 
    for(var j=0; j<eachRowData.columndetails.length; j++ ){
        var eachcolumnData = columndetails[j];
        alert(eachcolumnData.year);
    }
}
```